# How to authenticate to MS Graph using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, automation, microsoft-graph-api, azure-app-registration

I'm trying to develop an automation using `Graph API` and `JavaScript`. I have an app registration in Azure Portal with necessary permissions. How can I authenticate in my JavaScript automation using `tenant ID`, `client ID` and `client secret` and call Graph APIs from automation?

Comment: Hi, I think you might find a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#samples-and-guides) here.

Answer (score 1):

For your case, you can use the client [credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?tabs=http) to request the access token then call Graph API. See the link attached. Assumption: Your automation is a serverside daemon that authenticates and calls Graph API on its own

You can also look at this [complete sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-docs-code-javascript/ms-identity-docs-code-webapi-nodejs-client-credentials-flow/) for exactly your scenario. The sample contains guide and code sample to authenticate using client secret and then call MS graph API.